# TEMP Environment variable expansion for C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows

I need to get a `%TEMP%` environmental variable value string in Windows platform.

If I try to use any methods(C / C++) (`getenv()`, …) to get this environmental variable, it returns with `“~”` in that string.

For Example: C:\DOCUME~1\pkp\LOCALS~1\Temp.

But I need to get full string for some reasons, as below:

C:\Documents and Settings\pkp\Local Settings\Temp

If anyone knows any methodology to obtain this, please let me know.

Comment: Note that the names with ~ in them are "8.3 names". Many, if not all files on a Windows system have two names, a "long" name and an "8.3" name. This is a Windows-specific concept. The ~ is really part of the name and cannot be expanded.

Comment: What reason have you to believe that *isn't* the value of the environment variable? What do you see when you run `echo %TEMP%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `GetLongPathName()` on the short name.

Comment: Could you please suggest something in pure C++ i.e. without using the standard WINDOWS api.

Comment: But why do you find it bizarre. Is there any equivalent STL function for wordexp() http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wordexp.html

Comment: @anand: This is a Windows "feature", of course you're going to need to ask Windows for help in resolving it. There's no concept of Windows' 8.1 filenames in STL.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I dont have much idea OS other than windows. thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

DOCUME~1 is not an environment variable. It is a legacy naming convention from DOS still supported by windows for backward compatibility. Hence there is nothing to 'expand' in the environment variable sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992%28VS.85%29.aspx) it obliges you to include "windows.h" but I assume you how to do that anyway since you're writing a windows app.

Comment: Could you please suggest something in pure C++ i.e. without using the standard WINDOWS api

Comment: @anand - i'm not sure it's possible, except the way you did it with getenv